# Vue filter to add <br> for address

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a Vue filter which get's and then joins address details with a ,

```
Vue.filter('address', (address, countryNames = []) => {
  const formattedAddress = [
    address?.name,
    address?.company,
    address?.add1,
    address?.add2,
    address?.town,
    address?.county,
    address?.postcode,
    countryNames[address?.countryId],
  ]

  return formattedAddress.filter((value) => value).join(', ')
})
```

the result :

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I would like to add a `<br>` after the name and county to achieve[image]:

Is that possible via the filter?

Comment: What have you tried? You could directly add `<br>` elements and use `v-html` to set the value in your template or alternately, add newlines `\n` and use CSS `white-space` to control the display

Comment: Have you tried just do `.join('<br/>')`?

Comment: try using RegExp

Comment: You can set a CSS of `white-space: pre-wrap` and then insert `"\n"` whenever you need a new line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you want line break only after name and country fields and you have a control to create an array of the fields. You can apply that while assigning the items to the array itself.

Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    address: {
      name: 'Name',
      company: 'Company',
      town: 'Town',
      country: 'Country',
      postcode: 'Postcode'
    },
    formattedAddress: null
  },
  mounted() {
    this.formattedAddress = [
      this.address.name ? this.address.name + ',<br>' : undefined,
      this.address.company ? this.address.company + ',' : undefined,
      this.address.town ? this.address.town + ',' : undefined,
      this.address.country ? this.address.country + ',<br>' : undefined,
      this.address.postcode
    ];
    
    this.formattedAddress = this.formattedAddress.filter(value => value).join(' ')
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <p v-html="formattedAddress"></p>
</div>
```